# Where do I start designing a Custom Control that contains child objects?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I think this is a fun engineering-level question.

I need to design a control which displays a line chart.  What I want to be able to do is use a designer to add multiple `Pens` which actually describe the data and presentation so that it ends up with Xaml something along these lines:

```
<Chart>
  <Pen Name="SalesData" Color="Green" Data="..."/>
  <Pen Name="CostData" Color="Red" Data="..." />
  ...
</chart>
```

My first thought is to extend `ItemsControl` for the `Chart` class.  Will that get me where I want to go or should I be looking at it from a different direction such as extending `Panel`?

The major requirement is to be able to use it in a designer without adding any C# code.  In order for that to even be feasible, it needs to retain its structure in the tree-view model.  In other words, if I were working with this in Expression Blend or Mobiform Aurora, I would be able to select the chart from the logical tree or select any of the individual pens to edit their properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go with Chart as an ItemsControl and its ItemsPanel be a Canvas(For some light use I would go with Grid as ItemsPanel). And each Pen will be a CustomControl derived from PolyLine class. Does that make any sense?

Comment: Thanks, man.  That is exactly how I ended up implementing it.

Answer (score 1):

For those interested in making their own control from a personal development point of view (as stated in the original question) then I'd suggest a structure in this format.

```
<Chart>
  <Chart.Pens>
    <Pen Name="SalesData" Data="{Binding Name=SalesData}" />        
    <Pen Name="CostData">
      <Pen.Data>
        <PenData Y="12" X="Jan" />
        <PenData Y="34" X="Feb" />
      </Pen.Data>
    </Pen>
  </Chart.Pens>
</Chart>
```

For that you will need to expose a Pens collection in the user control (I would not see this as a derived ItemsControl control).  This derived user control will encapsulate other controls typically a grid to place a label for the heading, labels for the axis names, possibly a Canvas for the drawing area and a ItemsControl to display the items in the Legend.

---

### For those looking for a ready to go solution

For those looking for a ready to go solution then I'd check out CodePlex for [VisiFire's](http://www.codeplex.com/visifire/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=19717) WPF chart control.  It is WPF and Silverlight compatible and it even has a [Silverlight app](http://www.visifire.com/silverlight_chart_designer.php) for you to enter your data & style and have it generate XAML (or HTML) to paste into your application.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to extend Canvas for the chart and extend Shape for the Pens.  Then dynamically draw the shape based on the Color/Data properties.